# Firebase cloud storage rule for custom metadata

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

In firebase storage security rules, for delete permission, I want to check if a custom metadata key not exists in a file. I put `locked` key as custom metadata to reject delete requests. So, if a file do not have `locked` metadata it means it is allowed to delete.

What I tried so far:

```
allow delete: if resource.metadata.locked != true

allow delete: if !resource.metadata.locked
```

and even:

```
allow delete: if resource.metadata.size() == 0;
```

On Firebase console when I check the related files it is written "No metadata found".

But none of them above worked. How can I check if a file do not have a specific metadata key ?

Comment: I think the only allowed file metadata attributes are listed [here in firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties) So to access the locked attribute I believe it should be `resource.metadata.customMetadata.locked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rapidly done some tests with the Security Rules playground and here are the findings:

- If the Storage object does not have metadata, a rule like `if resource.metadata.locked != true` or `if resource.metadata.unlocked == "true"` will generate an error "Property metadata is undefined on object".
- If you set a custom metadata to Boolean `true` (e.g. in JavaScript `var metadata = {customMetadata: { locked: true },};)`, in the Security Rules, you should check for the **String** `true`.

**Conclusion**: You would need to have a custom metadata named `unlocked`, for example, and use the following rule:

`allow delete: if resource.metadata.unlocked == "true";`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. If there is metadata it works as explained. But problem is, my files do not have a default "locked" metadata. And when rules check it generates error as you said. Because in another rule case I have to check if any metadata exists. In docs they wrote: resource.metadata.size() == 1 in an example. But it doesn't work for zero. Do you know why doesnt it work for size zero ?

Comment: "In docs they wrote: `resource.metadata.size() == 1` in an example. But it doesn't work for zero. Do you know why does'nt it work for size zero?" => I think it is because of the same problem mentioned in the anwser "Property metadata is undefined on object". => Therefore you cannot call `size()`on it. I've tried to check `resource.metadata == null` or `undefined` but without success...

Comment: well it seems no way. I decided to set a default metadata "unlocked" and check it in the rules.